# How can I fix "reference broken" when publishing branch to Github?

Tags: git, github

When I try to publish my branch on Github using CTRL + P it comes up with this error message:

```
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/main': unable to resolve reference 'refs/remotes/origin/main': reference broken
From https://github.com/AlexPD93/React-Dictionary
 ! [new branch]      main       -> origin/main  (unable to update local ref)
```

Can anyone help me with how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: There's an existing question with no answer, but some helpful info in the comments: [github push fail error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/main](/q/69230664/4518341). Are you using GitHub Desktop? BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Note that CTRL-P is not a Git command: Git commands are run from the command line, and start with the word `git` and an action verb (e.g., `git commit`, `git push`). If you're doing this from some GUI (e.g., GitHub Desktop), use the appropriate tag for that GUI, and/or ask the GUI developers.